# Is it appropriate to use OO-style interfaces and classes when all you really need is function-like behavior?

Tags: python, function, class, oop, functional-programming

Is it appropriate to use OO-style interfaces and classes when all you really need is function-like behavior (i.e. no need to track or mutate state and the instance exists just to call its only exposed method once)?

For example, I often end up with (python) code that looks like this:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class IFoo(ABC):

  @abstractmethod
  def bar(self) -> str:
    ...


class ThisFoo(IFoo):
  def __init__(self, x: str):
    self._x = x

  def bar(self) -> str:
    return f'Doing this with {self._x}'


class ThatFoo(IFoo):
  def __init__(self, x: str):
    self._x = x

  def bar(self) -> str:
    return f'Doing that with {self._x}'
```

The only purpose of the Foo classes is for their `bar` methods to be called; and the client code only needs to call it once. In fact I will often include a convenience function to wrap this behavior:

```
def bar(type_: str, x: str) -> str:
  dispatcher = {
    'this': ThisFoo,
    'that': ThatFoo
  }
  Foo = dispatcher[type_]
  foo = Foo(x)
  return foo.bar()
```

Then the client code can call:

```
print(bar('this', 'baz'))
print(bar('that', 'baz'))
```

Now, a class-based approach is of course not really necessary. Here is an equivalent purely functional implementation:

```
def func_bar(type_: str, x: str) -> str:
  dispatcher = {
    'this': this_bar,
    'that': that_bar
  }
  func = dispatcher[type_]
  return func(x)


def this_bar(x: str) -> str:
  return f'Doing this with {x}'


def that_bar(x: str) -> str:
  return f'Doing that with {x}'


print(func_bar('this', 'baz'))
print(func_bar('that', 'baz'))
```

I think one could make the case that the class-based approach is inappropriate here because, one might argue, classes should only be used when you need an object to persist and to track mutable state, which isn't the case here. In fact in my Foo implementations I could've just as easily skipped the `__init__` definitions and specified `x: str` as a parameter in the `bar` method rather than have the `bar` method implementations reference the instance attribute `self._x`.

However, I believe there are a few advantages to the class-based approach.

**Contract Enforcement**

If I later need to add `OtherFoo` I will subclass the `IFoo` interface, and then static type-checkers like mypy will ensure that I add an appropriately defined `bar` method. By contrast, in the functional approach I might accidentally name my function `other_abr` and if I add that misspelled version to the dispatcher then static analysis tools will not catch the misspelling.

The functional approach I believe would still permit the type checker to catch an error in the signature of `other_bar` as long as it is added to the `func_bar` dispatcher. But if it doesn't get added to that function then there is no place in the code for static analysis to spot signature mismatch.

**Helper method/function organization**

Suppose `bar` needs implementations-specific helpers. In the class-based approach, the helpers would be private methods within the same class, e.g.:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class IFoo(ABC):

  @abstractmethod
  def bar(self) -> str:
    ...


class ThisFoo(IFoo):
  def __init__(self, x: str):
    self._x = x

  def bar(self) -> str:
    great_text = self._helper()
    return f'Doing this with {self._x}, {great_text}'

  def _helper(self) -> str:
    return f'{self._x} is great'


class ThatFoo(IFoo):
  def __init__(self, x: str):
    self._x = x

  def bar(self) -> str:
    great_text = self._helper()
    return f'Doing that with {self._x}, {great_text}'

  def _helper(self) -> str:
    return f'{self._x} is the greatest'
```

The helper methods live within their respective concrete classes, which makes it clear which helper is used for which implementation. By contrast, in the functional approach the most natural thing to do would be to define the helpers as stand-alone private functions, e.g.:

```
def this_bar(x: str) -> str:
  great_text = _this_bar_helper(x)
  return f'Doing this with {x}'


def _this_bar_helper(x: str) -> str:
  return f'{x} is great'


def that_bar(x: str) -> str:
  great_text = _that_bar_helper(x)
  return f'Doing that with {x}'


def _that_bar_helper(x: str) -> str:
  return f'{x} is the greatest'
```

But then it is less clear which helper belongs to which public function (naming conventions help, but are less robust than the class methods approach), especially if you have multiple helper methods, some of which are implementation-specific and some of which might be shared by all or multiple implementations.

I suppose an alternative could be to define the implementation-specific helper functions as nested functions within their respective public functions, but then you are mixing abstraction levels within the public function and making the code more difficult to read because it is broken up by the helper function definition.

**Convenience of avoiding nested parameter passing**

The above code also highlights this next point. In the class approach, both the public method and the private method could access `self._x`, but in the functional approach, the helper methods require parameters to be passed explicitly, which means more boilerplate code around function signatures and longer function bodies because they have to pass parameters to the helper functions. This gets especially awkward when you have parameters with default arguments and find yourself typing out the same default value across multiple nested helper function signatures.

Now, some might say this is a good thing because it forces the helper functions to be explicit about which parameters they actually need. But it makes it annoying to update your code if you need to change the signature of the public function, because you might also need to update its body (where the new parameter gets passed to the helper function) and the signatures and bodies of any nested helper functions. Whereas with the class-based approach the only signature update would be to the `__init__` method (or constructor in other languages).

Answer (score 1):

> Is it appropriate to use OO-style interfaces and classes when all you really need is function-like behavior?

No. If all you need is a function, then you should use a function.

If someone says their implementation is complicated enough to warrant using a class, they can still do so by simply defining a class with a `__call__` method. This doesn't work the other way round: if you require an object with a method, every implementer will have to create one and write the boilerplate, no matter how short and simple their `lambda` could have been.

> Contract Enforcement […] I might accidentally name my function `other_abr` and if I add that misspelled version to the dispatcher then static analysis tools will not catch the misspelling.

You're right that both the OOP and functional approaches let you specify the type that the dispatcher expects equally. I don't see what misspellings have to do with this, but static analysis also catches undeclared variables just fine.

> Helper method/function organization

You would absolutely nest the function definitions here. I don't see how that "mixes abstraction levels", and I would even consider that easier to read and more straightforward than having one public method somewhere in the class - unless you know the `IFoo` interface by heart, how can you quickly see that there's exactly on public method? The indentation of nested functions makes it very clear what's happening.

> Convenience […] in the functional approach, the helper methods require parameters to be passed explicitly, which means more boilerplate code around function signatures and longer function bodies because they have to pass parameters to the helper functions.

No they don't. If you nest the helper function definitions inside the function body, they can just access the outer function's variables by closure. Not having to create a `._x` private attribute actually requires less boilerplate.

Comment: By "mixes abstraction levels" I mean that within the public method body you now define an implementation of a helper method. The _call_ to the helper method is (or should be) at the same abstraction level as the other statements in the public method body, but that body is now also polluted with the _definition_ of the helper method, which is a lower level of detail.

Furthermore, suppose the helper needs its own helper which needs its own helper.. How many layers of nested helper function definitions would you advocate? They make the original method body more difficult to understand.

Comment: And what about helper functions that might be used across multiple functions? With a class-based approach you could put them in the abstract base class (so it would no longer be a pure interface, but still valid).

Comment: @Yakkanomica I do not think that a function definition pollutes anything. It is very much appropriate to put the definition at the same level as the calls to the function, as they are all part of the same public function implementation. The helper function implementation is removed from that level of abstraction by one more level of indentation, which seems fitting. It doesn't make the outer method implementation harder to understand since you can quickly skip over it. IMHO, you can use as many levels of nesting as you see fit. Of course, this is all subjective.

Comment: @Yakkanomica For helper functions that should be shared, you can't avoid passing things as parameters, but in my experience this is not that much of a problem if the helper function is actually large enough to warrant the sharing. Depending on the language, you'd use not many parameters but bundle them into a single record structure (object), which decreases the syntactic overhead. But I think that using OOP inheritance is definitely the wrong solution to implement sharing of helper functions.

Answer (score 0):

To address my own question – a "happy medium" approach I've started using is to implement functions as classes with a single public class method, with that method typically being named `do`, `make`, or `exec` depending on the context. As applied to the example in my initial post this might look like:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class IBar(ABC):

  @classmethod
  @abstractmethod
  def do(cls, x: str) -> str:
    ...


class ThisBar(IBar):

  @classmethod
  def do(cls, x: str) -> str:
    great_text = cls._helper(x)
    return f'Doing this with {x}, {great_text}'

  @classmethod
  def _helper(cls, x: str) -> str:
    return f'{x} is great'


class ThatBar(IBar):

  @classmethod
  def do(cls, x: str) -> str:
    great_text = cls._helper(x)
    return f'Doing that with {x}, {great_text}'

  @classmethod
  def _helper(cls, x: str) -> str:
    return f'{x} is the greatest'
```

What I like about this approach is that it retains the primary benefits of the class-based approach: namely the polymorphic benefits of interfaces, the clarity of nominal subtyping, and the clarity of helper functions as belonging to specific implementations. But by eschewing instance methods and variables it is clear that there is no mutable state or object to instantiate that might or might not persist.

I'd be curious to hear what people think of this approach. I don't presume to have invented it, but haven't seen it discussed elsewhere.